# Arranging Byes in a match fixture knockout (Switching Row Values) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm probably way off here but here's what I want to do. I have tblFixtures which holds Guid's of players who have been drawn to play each other in a Pool Knockout. tblFixtures has uniqueidentifier columns player1 and player2. I have already added 'Byes' because total players needed for a knockout like this is 8.. so for example, if a there's only 6 players in tblFixtures, it adds 2 blank players with Guid of '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. Therefore 2 players will get a 'Free pass to the next round (A 'Bye') but I need to re-arrange the table in case a BYE ends up drawn against a BYE like this.

```
Player 1                                 Player 2
{72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261A333} v {9C90B324-78CA-4C7B-BC79-15537F3935B2}
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} v {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
{3E828BB1-AEC2-4543-BD26-E12AD886D2E8} v {72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261ABC2} 
{4F9C3964-2672-4413-8A01-2ED09CA7A711} v {AFEB20EB-5CCB-4302-A999-CC772F8ABACE}
```

I need it to put the empty Guid's ANYWHERE against a players Guid like this..

```
Player 1                                 Player 2
{72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261A333} v {9C90B324-78CA-4C7B-BC79-15537F3935B2}
{3E828BB1-AEC2-4543-BD26-E12AD886D2E8} v {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} v {72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261ABC2} 
{4F9C3964-2672-4413-8A01-2ED09CA7A711} v {AFEB20EB-5CCB-4302-A999-CC772F8ABACE}
```

The code below requires OVER command and a few tweaks I think, but this is as far as I could get. What I am trying to do is check how many players (including BYES) there are, so in this case there's 8 and that's stored in @matches. Now I want it to check a row at a time, using a loop equal to the amount stored in @matches.. This check looks for a blank 0's Guid playing a blank 0's Guid. If it is found then it will replace Player1 in this row with the next none blank player1 Guid it finds and zero that one out instead.

I just don't know understand OVER yet and unsure the rest of the code will actually work OR does anyone know an easier way to do this?

Any help appreciated. Here's what I have so far..

```
DECLARE @matchess int
SELECT @matches = COUNT(accountID) from tblFixtures)*

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0

WHILE @cnt < @matches
    BEGIN
    If (SELECT Player1 FROM tblFixtures WHERE ROW_NUMBER()=@cnt) = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND SELECT(player1 FROM tblFixtures WHERE ROW_NUMBER()= @cnt) ='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblFixtures SET Player1 = SELECT(TOP(1) player1 FROM tblFixtures WHERE player1 <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND ROW_NUMBER()>@cnt) WHERE ROW_NUMBERr()=@cnt
            UPDATE tblFixtures SET Player1 = '0000-0000-0000-0000' WHERE SELECT(Top(1) player1) <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND ROW_NUMBER()>@cnt 
        END
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: The need to do this is a bit messy. I’d change the code that generates those rows in the first place to not have the possibility that a bye can play a bye. E.g you have 6 players and 2 byes. Number the player one slots 1..4 and the player two slots 5..8. Reserve slots 7 and 8 for the byes. Randomly sort the 6 players and allocate to slots 1..6.

Comment: If there are 5 players you would have 2 playing each other, while three are moving forward against byes? If this is what you want, it might be enough to add the byes on one side only?

Comment: The right amount of Byes are added before this stage and everything works apart from I just need to switch it in the event that 2 byes are drawn against each other ? I appreciate your help if you can suggest a way to do this ?

Comment: “Everything works” apart from it can return wrong results, so change the method to just return correct results instead of fixing them up afterwards. I’ll add some code to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fix this earlier in the process.

Assuming you have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Players(Player UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

INSERT INTO Players
SELECT '{72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261A333}' UNION ALL
SELECT '{3E828BB1-AEC2-4543-BD26-E12AD886D2E8}' UNION ALL 
SELECT '{4F9C3964-2672-4413-8A01-2ED09CA7A711}' UNION ALL
SELECT '{9C90B324-78CA-4C7B-BC79-15537F3935B2}' UNION ALL
SELECT '{72462373-6B64-4427-9F9F-9A872261ABC2}' UNION ALL
SELECT '{AFEB20EB-5CCB-4302-A999-CC772F8ABACE}';
```

You can use the following to generate only valid ties ([demo](http://rextester.com/KEDK50970))

```
WITH  T AS
(
SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))  AS Rn, 
         ceiling(power(2, ceiling(log(COUNT(*) OVER())/log(2))) / 2.0) AS MatchCount
FROM Players
)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Rn <= MatchCount THEN Player END),
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Rn > MatchCount THEN Player END), 
            '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}')
FROM T
GROUP BY Rn%MatchCount;
```

Rather than generating invalid ones that you then need to fix up.

Comment: Wow that's impressive! I can't understand a lot of it but basically I am taking the players from tblEntrants and wanting to store them in tblFixtures under column names player1 and player2.. I would love to use this if you could please somehow show me how to store them in tblFixtures. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just add `INSERT INTO tblFixtures(Player1,Player2)` immediately before the second `Select`

Comment: You're a genius! This works perfectly, just what I needed. I'll study up to try and work out how it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Impressive solution

Comment: I completely agree.. there's some serious stuff going on in such a short amount of code.